# How do I auto download .jar files with Php

Tags: php, jar, download

I have looked for an answer for to long, I have the auto download and redirect done, I just need it to make the .jar file download properly. It keeps getting an error when you download and open it.

It says "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:/path/Final frontier(Pre-Alpha 0.3).jar"

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: 'application/jar', 'true'");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Final frontier (Pre-> Alpha 0.3).jar"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("public_html/paid/game/Final frontier (Pre-Alpha 0.3).jar"));

$fp = fopen("public_html/paid/game/Final frontier (Pre-Alpha 0.3).jar", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the code, thanks, but its still not working...

Comment: this `fopen("public_html/` seems like it may be playing tricks on you. I'd either remove it `fopen("paid/` if the script's running from the root, or `fopen("../paid/` as an added example, or use a full server path. I.e. `fopen("/var/usr/you/public_html/paid/`

Comment: same thing for `filesize("public_html/`

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! That worked!

Comment: You're welcome. I  have posted an answer for it below @TJGames you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Thanks you so much!!! That worked! – TJGames 1 min ago"*

Comments to answer, since it solved the question.

This `fopen("public_html/` seems like it may be playing tricks on you. I'd either remove it `fopen("paid/` if the script's running from the root, or `fopen("../paid/` as an added example, or use a full server path. I.e. `fopen("/var/usr/you/public_html/paid/`

Do the same thing for `filesize("public_html/`